# How to store polymorphic related models

Tags: eloquent

I am working on a system that have lots of users each has his own information so I needed to create a model for each. On the other hand, all those users have a common user model where their credentials being collected form those requirements it was suitable to have a polymorphic relation between all user types and the user model i.e., coordinator as a model and the user as a model I did the following

```
class Coordinator extends Model
{
    protected $fillable= ['userid', ...];
    ...

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(User::class, 'userable');
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    ...

    public function userable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        ...
        $table->morphs('userable');
    }
}

class CreateCoordinatorsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $table->bigIncrements('coordid');
        ...
       $table->foreign('userid')->references('ID')->on('wp_users')->onDelete('cascade');
    }
}
```

After migration I noticed that columns `userable_type` and `userable_id` not allowing `null`. How come I create a coordinator entity with its associated user entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it after googling...

[Laravel One to Many Polymorphic Relationship - Create Records](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-one-to-many-polymorphic-relationship-tutorialexample.html)

The idea is not as I thought at the beginning. When I used the `$table->morphs('userable');` the user table had two columns, userable_id and userable_type, and each allows no null by default and by ORM convention and I was thinking that they consider the user table is the master and other tables (i.e., coordinator, educator, shipper etc.) each as the detail table. According to this initial wrong understanding I was adding a userid column at each table to store the related user id for each specific user type and I was wondering how I am going to save the user that needs the userable_id and userable_type to be filled by saving the specific user first to get its id that will be provided to the user's userable_id the case resembles a deadlock situation as each table needs a piece of information that will be known after storing data on each to be able to save data to each table, wired!!!.

However, when I read the article in the above link I figured that it considers the table in an opposite way, unlike my thinking was (i.e., coordinator, shipper, etc. are the masters and the user table is the detail). That is for guys who use the models directly but for those who use repository package it is a little bit tricky and you need to do an extra work...